# How tall are the pillars of creation? (angular and physical) How bright are they?

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing, nebula, james-webb-space-telescope

NASA's October 19, 2022 [NASA’s Webb Takes Star-Filled Portrait of Pillars of Creation](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2022/nasa-s-webb-takes-star-filled-portrait-of-pillars-of-creation) shows a sparkly and beautiful infrared image of the [Astronomical elephant trunks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_trunk_(astronomy)) known as the [Pillars of Creation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillars_of_Creation).

The Wikipedia article doesn't seem to give any amateur observing-relevant information like angular size or visual magnitude, nor their actual physical size.

**Question:** How tall are the pillars of creation in angular and physical dimension? How bright are they?

I wonder if they can at least be spotted as a faint fuzzy spot in an amateur telescope?

---

From the linked NASA item; left: Hubble, right: includes JWST

[image: from NASA's October 19, 2022 "NASA’s Webb Takes Star-Filled Portrait of Pillars of Creation" https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2022/nasa-s-webb-takes-star-filled-portrait-of-pillars-of-creation]

> NASA's Hubble Space Telescope made the Pillars of Creation famous with its first image in 1995, but revisited the scene in 2014 to reveal a sharper, wider view in visible light, shown above at left. A new, near-infrared-light view from NASA’s James Webb Space Telescope, at right, helps us peer through more of the dust in this star-forming region. The thick, dusty brown pillars are no longer as opaque and many more red stars that are still forming come into view.
> Credits: NASA, ESA, CSA, STScI; Joseph DePasquale (STScI), Anton M. Koekemoer (STScI), Alyssa Pagan (STScI).

Comment: The pillars of creation are *dark* clouds. They are visible because of the background being bright.

Comment: They are quite large and bright compared to other objects amateurs might look at, I have photographed them a few times from my very light polluted (Bortle 8) back yard.  I don't think I've ever tried to see them visually from a dark site.  They are part of a larger nebula called the Eagle Nebula or M16.  If you download a program like Stellarium, you can search for that and measure the size.

Comment: @planetmaker except where they aren't

Comment: @GregMiller Thanks! Then I will try to have a look some day with my 8x42 binoculars